# How to set checkbox value non editable once we selected?

Tags: asp.net, html

I have a html page which consists of 10 checkboxes. When i tick on some checkboxes and submit the form,the checkbox values are stored in the database. Now i need a help, when i take the same html page after submission, i want to view the ticked checkboxes as ticked and those ticked checkboxes couldn't be unticked. Please help .

```
<form action="Post.aspx" method="post" target="_blank" > <td><input id="c101" value="101" type="Checkbox" runat="server"/></td> <td><input id="c102" value="102" type="Checkbox" runat="server"/></td> <td><input id="c103" value="103" type="Checkbox" runat="server"/></td> </tr>
```

Comment: Disable those check boxes

Comment: <form action="Post.aspx" method="post" target="_blank"  > <td><input id="c101" value="101" type="Checkbox" runat="server"/></td>
    <td><input id="c102" value="102" type="Checkbox" runat="server"/></td>
    <td><input id="c103" value="103" type="Checkbox" runat="server"/></td>
  </tr>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code will do it in the code ,

```
CheckBox1.Enabled = true;
CheckBox1.Checked = true;
```

Following code will do it in the JavaScript,

```
$("input:checked").click(function(){ return false; });
```

Comment: but where will i write these codes ? i have an html page for creating checkboxes and submit button and a Post.aspx page for posting the values of html page and for writing the db connectivity.

Comment: opps... You are coding like in clasic asp or php